# Retrieve User ID in ASP.Net Bearer Tokens WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, bearer-token

I've implemented a WebApi with Bearer token authentication and often I've to know the UserId stored on DB without read data from DB.
In old Asp.Net WebServices (asmx) I used session to store my DB User Object but WebApi are stateless.

How can I do it?

Thanks for your helps :)

Comment: What all the contents of your token???

Comment: Hi Karthik, what do you mean? it's a bearer token...
My Bearer token authentication is ok but often, when clients call web API, I've to know the ID of the Logged in User without reading it from DB every time...

Comment: you can cache the users details on application start, if you cannot do that i don't think you can avoid a DB call on each request.